# Web server failed to start. Port was already in use error. but application is still running

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

I am making a spring boot application. Everything worked fine until two days ago.
When I start my application I get:

"APPLICATION FAILED TO START.
Web server failed to start. Port 8443 was already in use."

But.... when I check my postman the application IS running.... So the error shouldn't be there. I would really appreciate some help here. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.
I already tried diffrent ports but that is not the problem.

This is my "application.properties"

```
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:certificate.jks
server.ssl.key-store-type=pkcs12
server.ssl.key-store-password=password
server.ssl.key-password=password
server.ssl.key-alias=certificate
server.port=8443

spring.jpa.show-sql=true

spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.platform=postgres
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/java_backend_eind3
spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.database=POSTGRESQL
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect= org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto= create
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always

logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type=TRACE
```

and my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>nl.eind.java</groupId>
    <artifactId>backend</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>backend</name>
    <description>Java eindopdracht </description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: It's running because you haven't stopped it, and when you try to re-run it it says it can't re-assign port that's already in use. Kill the previously running instance and run again.

Comment: Better terminate the JVM instance(running server) and start again

Comment: Sometimes when you force close your IDE without stopping the tomcat server then JVM does not get terminated and you get this issue, try killing java task/process and it works.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, how do i kill it tho...? the normal stop option can't be selected because it's not running.

Comment: @lisa from your operating system (which we don't know), i.e. Windows' task manager or with the `kill` command on *nix environments

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I am looking in my windows task manager but i can't see anything running...

Comment: @lisa under Detail look for a `java.exe`. If there's more than one, as an heuristic, you should probably kill the one consuming more RAM.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Thanks! it seems to be working for now!

Answer (score 4):

if you are running on windows, you can find the process running on port and kill that process using below command, so that port will be freed

```
netstat -ano | findstr :8443
taskkill /pid "EnterProcessIdHere" /F
```

For linux

```
lsof -i :8443
kill EnterProcessIdHere
```

Answer (score 0):

to catch java.net.BindException e with message: Address already in use

```
try {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    } catch (org.springframework.boot.web.server.PortInUseException e) {
//Runtime.exec("pkil")..
//or
SpringApplication.run(Application.class, otherargs);
//SpringApplication.run(Application.class, new String[]{"--server.port=8444"});
//when invoked recursively it is a port rebalancer for port usage among port pool with server as from client for startup stage via application restarts within many busy ports which are used before or without querying.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to eclipse's Console window and click red Stop button to stop Tomcat and/or click 'Remove All Terminated Launches' and then re-run spring boot app.

It clears/purges previous app instances bound to port.